# Magento2: Add product attribute as Media Image

Tags: attributes, magento2

I had an issue when we add a product attribute as a Media Image type. I created the attribute successfully through the backend.

But it is not displaying in the Add Product page in the back end. I selected the corresponding attribute in Add Attribute area also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, I got the proper way to solve this problem.
We can add media images through the section "Images and Videos".
After uploading the image, just click on that image and specify it as an attribute image.

Comment: and did you find a way to use it in phtml?

Comment: This is a weird workflow. Definitely going to confuse our content managers.

Comment: @VIPIn A ROY, Its worked but the path is showing at product tabs instead of image. check https://www.depoto.com/spanner.html at product tabs

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is a bug with custom Media Attributes. You can read about this on [forum](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-Feature-Requests-and/Media-image-attribute-in-product-listing/idi-p/47131). I resolve this by entering Browser Inspector and display proper tab (Storefront Properties) in Magento 2 Admin Panel (just remove display:none style), to set "Used in Product Listing" to Yes. Then you can use this in .phtml file by code:

```
$product->getCustomAttribute( 'attribute_code' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment on the answer from [Jan Żaba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6882397/jan-%C5%BBaba), but I just wanted to make it a bit more clear:

If you edit the custom image attribute from the admin panel:
**Stores > Attributes > Product**

Inspect the **Attribute Information** menu on the left. You will notice that the third **<li />** element in the menu has a **"display: none"** inline style declaration on it. Remove the **"display: none"** declaration and edit the **Storefront Properties**.

There you can set the following settings to **Yes**:

- Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront
- Used in Product Listing

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of late but for future reference. Tt is not displaying as not an individual attribute not because it is a bug but because the created attribute is instead added in the image tab as a selection.